# What are all the ways that stacking resistance becomes immunity by RAW?

Tags: dnd-5e, stacking, damage-resistance, immunities

In [this supplement for Rise of Tiamat](https://media.wizards.com/2014/downloads/dnd/RiseTiamatSupplementv0.2.pdf), on page 4, the properties of the "dragon mask" magic items are described, including this property (**bold** emphasis mine):

> ***Damage Absorption.*** You have resistance against the mask’s damage type. **If you already have resistance to that damage type from another source, you instead have immunity to that damage type.** If you already have immunity to that damage type from another source, whenever you are subjected to damage of that type, you take none of that damage and regain a number of hit points equal to half the damage dealt of that type.

Off the top of my head, I cannot think of any other feature, be it class feature, racial feature or magic item, that allows multiple forms of resistance to stack and become immunity to either a damage type or a condition. Is this a unique feature of the dragon masks (I'm not so interested in the part about regaining hit points after the part I emphasised, just the part about stacking resistances that I emphasised), or are there are features or magic items RAW that allow stacked resistances to become immunity?

Comment: Related: [Barring Epic Boons, is there a way to gain immunity to fire damage?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/160074)

Comment: Technically speaking this doesn't really "stack" resistances. It's a conditional statement that gives you a different property based on if you have resistance/immunity or not.

Comment: I find the last ability even stronger; I'm imagining a caster standing deadcenter in the middle of its AoE spells... healing any damage they took and killing enemies in the same action.

Comment: @MatthieuM. That healing requires that *"...you **already** have immunity to that damage type from another source..."*

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[This particular search](https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=resistance%20immunity&f=equipment,magic-items,spells,backgrounds,classes,feats,races&c=items,spells,characters) on DND Beyond reveals 1 racial trait, 2 spells, and 21 magic items having both "resistance" and "immunity" in their descriptions. The only items appearing having the sought after property are the ones already observed: the [dragon masks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=dragon%20mask&f=equipment,magic-items&c=items).

Is this a thorough enough search? I would think so. An ability, spell description, or magic item certainly must contain both the words "resistance" and "immunity" (or one of their forms, I tried all those combinations as well), so if it exists, it at least is not on DND Beyond.

Now for the details of my reasoning.

First, we have the [rules for damage resistance](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#DamageResistanceandVulnerability):

> Multiple instances of resistance or vulnerability that affect the same damage type count as only one instance.

And of course, [specific beats general](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/introduction#SpecificBeatsGeneral):

> If a specific rule contradicts a general rule, the specific rule wins.

The *general* rule is that multiple instances of resistance count as one. For a particular rule to trump this, *it must be a specific rule that mentions resistance and immunity*. The idea is that for it to be specific for the purposes of satisfying *specific-beats-general*, it must cite resistance to override normal resistance rules, and it must cite immunity to grant immunity.